# Best way to lazy initialize struct members?

Tags: rust, struct, initialization, lazy-initialization

I have this struct:

```
pub struct NonSteamGame {
    app_id:String ,
    app_name:String,
    start_dir:String,
    icon:String,
    shortcut_path:String,
    launch_options:String,
    is_hidden:bool,
    allow_desktop_config:bool,
    allow_overlay:bool,
    open_vr:bool,
    devkit:bool,
    devkit_game_id:String,
    devkit_override_app_id:String,
    last_play_time:String,
    flatpack_app_id:String
}
```

All these field values are read from a stream and set as they are read.

Is there any way to be able to create an instance without manually initializing all the struct members to assign them as I get their values from the stream? An example (pseudo code):

```
let nsg = NonSteamGame {} //Do not initialize all values manually here

... get property_name and value from stream...

match property_name {
    "appid" => nsg.app_id = String::new(value)
    "AppName" => nsg.app_name = String::new(value)
    "StartDir" => ...
    "icon" => ...
}
```

I know I could use #[derive(Default)] for scalar types but it seems it doesn't work for String type.

Comment: `Default` is implemented for `String`. Could you explain what's not working in more detail?

Comment: When I'm using something like let a = NonSteamGame{}; I'm getting a bunch of errors stating that app_id,et... is missing in the structure fields. Perhaps this is not the correct syntax?

Comment: You could try the builder pattern. [This crate](https://docs.rs/derive_builder/latest/derive_builder/) even writes the builder for your struct

Comment: @Notbad once you derive `Default`, use `NonSteamGame::default()` to get an an instance of your struct with default values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best option for this case would be to derive the Default trait.

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct NonSteamGame {
    app_id:String ,
    app_name:String,
...
```

Then, instead of `::new()`, instantiate with `NonSteamGame::default()`.
You can even make the `new` facade if you need to keep the backward compatibility:

```rust
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
```